# Variadic templates, recursion, non-typename parameters

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

Am trying to build some simple variadic template with non-typename parameters:

```
  #include <iostream>

  void myf()
  {
  }

  template<int Arg1, int ... Args> void myf()
  {
     std::cout << Arg1 << ", ";
     myf<Args...>();
  }

  int main()
  {
     myf<1,2,3,4,5>();
  }
```

Trying to compile this and got:

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void myf() [with int Arg1 = 5; int ...Args = {}]’:
test.cpp:10:18:   recursively required from ‘void myf() [with int Arg1 = 2; int ...Args = {3, 4, 5}]’
test.cpp:10:18:   required from ‘void myf() [with int Arg1 = 1; int ...Args = {2, 3, 4, 5}]’
test.cpp:15:20:   required from here
test.cpp:10:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘myf()’
     myf<Args...>();
              ^
test.cpp:10:18: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:7:39: note: template<int Arg1, int ...Args> void myf()
     template<int Arg1, int ... Args> void myf()
                                   ^
test.cpp:7:39: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:10:18: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘Arg1’
     myf<Args...>();
```

It seems, recursion termination not working. What is the correct way to terminate non-typename variadic template recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution would be to have the last case as the *one parameter case* instead of the *no parameter case*. The problem is that your last call expands to this:

```
myf<>();
```

Which is not quite valid.

Instead, you might want to do this:

```
// one parameter case:
template<int Arg>
void myf()
{
    std::cout << Arg << std::endl;
}

// two or more parameters:
template<int Arg1, int Arg2, int... Args>
void myf()
{
   std::cout << Arg1 << ", " << Arg2 << ", ";
   myf<Args...>();
}
```

Here's a live example at [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d97f9c6cda64c37c)